# What is the difference between an object literal and a class in JavaScript?

Tags: javascript

I am currently finding it hard to figure out the difference between an object literal and a class.

Comment: To start things, an object literal is not a function. Please refer to a tutorial, or give a more specific point, where you are confused.

Comment: One is `{name: "hello"}` the other `class Person() {}; new Person()`

Comment: If you need multiple instances of your object (ie: you have more than one version of that object), then a class is probably the way you need to go, if you have only need one instance, then you could probably use an object literal (using a class still wouldn't hurt though)

Comment: just search your question on google, you'll get thousand of article and videos!

Comment: feeling bit hopeful@NickParsons

Answer (score 2):

Here's [a link](http://www.lottejackson.com/learning/javascript-notes-classes-object-literal)!

This might be helpful for you.

Content of the link:

> The most significant difference I can see between creating classes and
>   literally notated objects is that the latter are entire objects,
>   whereas classes are not objects, but blueprints from which objects are
>   created.